# JAVA Method Calling Query

Tags: java

```
class Temp
{
    private Temp(int data)
    {
        System.out.printf(" Constructor called ");
    }

    protected static Temp create(int data)
    {
        Temp obj = new Temp(data);
        return obj;
    }

    public void myMethod()
    {
        System.out.printf(" Method called ");
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Temp obj = Temp.create(20); //How this is a method call?
        obj.myMethod();
    }
}
```

In the above program, the commented line is not understandable for me.
Can anyone give me a good explanation about how the static method is called using object creation?

Comment: Temp obj = Temp.create(20); //How this is a method call?
   obj.myMethod();
Then why did we use this? and what is temp.create (20)?

Comment: the static method is not called using object creation, the object is created by use of a static method. the static method exists before any instances exist, and will still be available if all instances are removed. In your code, the constructor is private, so can't be accessed from outside the class, meaning you'll need some construction (like a static method) to callit

Comment: protected static Temp create(int data)--> Is this a constructor or method how can i identify?

Comment: static means class level, I think if you understand what static vs instance is/does, you'll understand the concept pretty quick. Read through this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: a constructor always has [access modifier] [name of the class] (parameters) as signature. There is no return type or void in it (ever), so the create(int data) is clearly a method

Comment: private Temp (int data) { ... is your constructor

Comment: Temp.creat(20) is method call ?

Comment: and why did we use Temp(class name ) in the method?

Comment: what do you mean by Temp(class name) ? I've tried to explain it a bit more in an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
class Temp
{
    private Temp(int data)
    {
        System.out.printf(" Constructor called ");
    }
    protected static Temp create(int data)
    {Temp obj = new Temp(data);
        return obj;
    }
    public void myMethod()
    {
        System.out.printf(" Method called ");
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Temp obj = Temp.create(20); //How this is a method call?
        obj.myMethod();
    }
}
```

A constructor of a class always follows a same signature:
[access modifier -> protected, public, private, default] [name of the class] (parameters)

So, in your code,

```
private Temp(int data) {
  System.out.printf(" Constructor called ");
}
```

is your constructor.

In order to use your `Temp` class, at least the non-static members of it, you'll need an instance of the class to be able to use it, but, since your constructor is declared private, an instance can only be created within the very same class.

That is what you do here:

```
protected static Temp create(int data)
        {Temp obj = new Temp(data);
            return obj;
        }
```

This method is a static method, meaning it 'exists' as soon as the class is loaded in the memory, even without the class being instantiated.
Since it is declared protected, not private, it can be used by subclasses of `Temp`, and by classes that are in the same package as `Temp`, like your `Test` class.

Your `Test` class calls this method, which calls the constructor, and returns the created instance to the `Test` class. This way of working is used in certain scenario's, for instance if you want to limit the number of instances created per VM, like with the `Singleton` pattern.

Comment: 'protected static Temp create(int data)
        {Temp obj = new Temp(data);
            return obj;
        }'
in the above method why we have written 'Temp' that is class name in mwthod?

Comment: because you are calling a static method (create) from the Temp class. It is possible to call static methods through an instance, but for this one, it's not always possible (you can only have an instance after calling this method)

Answer (score 0):

A `static` method means that it can be called without creating an Object of that class, in your example `Temp` item.

```
 static Temp create(int data)
```

The `static` word in your method is what is allowing you to do that.
The method is then callable in a static way, which means using *className.methodName*, in your example, `Temp.create()`

And since your method is returning a `Temp` object, you are putting that into a Temp object

```
Temp obj = Temp.create(20);
```

In the `Temp obj` you are putting the result of the object created in your method, in the line

```
{Temp obj = new Temp(data);
    return obj; //this is your object
}
```

Comment: So , while returning a object in method , we need to create the object for that method? is this what you wanna say?

Comment: The object that is returning is the one that you have created with `Temp obj = new Temp(data);` . The `Temp obj` is where you are putting the object created into the method. I also add this info in my answer

Comment: No, the method creates the Object by calling the constructor